# Help needed for simple probability mutually exclusive problem?

Tags: calculus, probability

[Probability Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFpaK.png)

Please see the image above. I know that the answer is 0.75 but can someone please explain how to arrive at that answer? I would sincerely appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I understand logic behind the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that neither occurs is $.6$.  Then probability that one, the other, or both occur is $1 - .6 = .4$.  Then probability that both occur is $.1$ The probability that one or then other but not both is $.4 -.1 = .3$.  The probability that one or the other but not both happens given that one, or the other, or both must happen is $\frac {.3}{.4} = .75$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear, concise, and detailed explanation. I immediately understood the thought process.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A \cup B) = 1 - P((A\cup B)^c)=0.4$$
$$P(E|A\cup B)=\frac{P(E\cap( A \cup B))}{P(A\cup B)} =\frac{P(A\cup B) - P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)}= \frac{0.4-0.1}{0.4}=\frac{0.3}{0.4}=0.75$$

Comment: Thank you for your mathematical explanation. This is extremely helpful for the logic behind the answer.